# For which $(a,b)$, $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^{b}}{x^{a}}dx$ is finite

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I want to find all pairs $(a,b)$ where $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{(\ln x)^{b}}{x^{a}}dx$ is finite.

I found some parts of the solution. For instance, when $b<-2$ and $a>1$ or when $b=1$ and $a>2$, this integral is finite. But I don't know how to analyze it in general. Is there any way to see all $(a,b) $ easier?

Comment: May be this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3702921/for-which-values-of-p-q-does-the-integral-%e2%88%ab10xpln1xqdx-converge/3702993#3702993

Comment: A related post here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3723448/find-the-real-values-of-p-and-q-such-that-following-integral-converges/3723795#3723795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convergence of this integral is related to convergence of [Bertrand's Series](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A9rie_de_Bertrand) through application the integral test.  But we need to be careful due to the possible singularity at $x=1^+$ arising from $\log^b(x)$ for $b<0$.

One way to see things a bit clearer is to enforce the substitution $x\mapsto e^x$.  Proceeding, we obtain

$$\int_1^\infty \frac{\log^b(x)}{x^a}\,dx=\int_0^\infty x^be^{(1-a)x}\,dx\tag 1$$

And now the singularity at $x=1$ for $b<0$ of the integrand on the left-hand side of $(1)$ is more transparent by looking at the singularity at $x=0$ for $b<0$ of the integrand on the right-hand side of $(1)$.

From the right-hand side of $(1)$, it is straightforward to see that the integral diverges for $a\le 1$ and converges for $a>1$ and $b>-1$.

Comment: I am trying to understand your explanation but I couldn't see the result for just the case $a>1$ and  $b<0$. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: For $a>1$, the exponential decay overwhelms any possible power of $x$.  So, the integral $\int_1^\infty x^be^{-x}\,dx$ converges.  If $-1<b<0$, then for small $x$ the integrand behaves like $\frac1{x^{|b|}}$ and $\int_0^1 \frac1{x^{|b|}}\,dx=\left.\left(\frac{x^{1-|b|}}{1-|b|}\right)\right|_0^1=\frac1{1-|b|}$ exists.

Comment: I understood all cases. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And pleased to hear that you have it now.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Let $$f(x)=\frac{(\ln(x))^b}{x^a}$$
Assume $ b\ge 0$.
$ f $ is continuous at $[1,+\infty)$, so it is locally integrable and positive at $ [1,+\infty)$.

If $ a>1$  then catch $\alpha \in (1,a)$.

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^{\alpha}f(x)=0$$
$$\implies 0\le f(x) \le \frac{1}{x^\alpha} $$
for $ x$ great enough.
thus the integral converges.

If $ a<1 $, take $ \beta\in (a,1)$

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x^\beta f(x)=+\infty$$
$$\implies \frac{1}{x^\beta}\le f(x)$$
for $ x $ great enough.
then the integral diverges.

If $ a=1$, then for $ X>1$

$$\int_1^Xf(x)dx=\Bigl[\frac{(\ln(x))^{b+1}}{b+1}\Bigr]_1^X$$

the integral converges $ \iff b+1<0$

I let for you the cases $ a=1$ and $ b<0$.

Comment: How on earth does the integral converge for $a=1$ and any value of $b$?  If $a=1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty} \log^{b+1}(x)=\infty$ for $b+1>0$, and $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\log^{b+1}(x)=\infty$ for $b+1<0$.  For $a=1$ and $b=1$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}\log^2(x)=\infty$.  So, the integral fails to converge for $a\le 1$ for all $b$.

Comment: Your post has fatal flaws and should be either corrected or deleted as it is misleading.